# OAuth with Next js and nextAuth

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth, next-auth

after using NextAuth.js with the Google provider in Next.js without a backend or database
It is return session cookie
, why still get a session cookie after a successful login?

I'm still very puzzled by this, and I'm still a beginner in using this library.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.